# What alternitives are there to WCF Test Client?

Tags: wcf, wcftestclient

I feel like it should be easier to test my WCF Services.

Is there an alternative to WCF Test Client?

Something with these features:

1. Can save my object trees (method parameters) to be used again.
2. Ideally it would even let me identify GUIDs that need to be re-generated on each run and ones that should stay static.
3. Easier to deal with arrays, lists and nullable types. (For example, if I have an array of nullable types, I have to enter the length of the array and that that each one is not null before I can fill in values.  It just seems that there should be an easier way....)
4. Can save the "Config File" between runs.  (My services return more data than the standard 65,536 in MaxBufferSize and MaxReceivedMessageSize.)

Free is best, but if I have to pay to get a good tool I will consider it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I use [WCF Storm LITE](http://wcfstorm.com/wcf/wcfstorm-lite.aspx) to test my WCF services.  It's more user-friendly than WCF Test Client, although the free version has limited features compared to its commercial counterpart.

Answer (score 5):

SOAPUI is the best I found so far.  It can even be used to test RESTful services as well.

It has a community edition (free) and a pro edition.  AFAIK, the community edition is not feature restricted.  The benefits of Pro edition, besides the technical support, is the time-saving features like database-driven requests and nice UI editor for composing the request.  In the community edition, you'll have to get your hands dirty and work with the xml.

http://www.soapui.org

Comment: It's also incredibly bloated. For some reason it's taking up >500 MB of memory to open a handful of xml files.

Answer (score 1):

I am the developer of an opensource tool called WsdlUI that can be used instead of WCFTestClient. It can be integrated into Visual Studio to use instead of WCFTestClient.

It can be downloaded at https://drexyia.github.io/WsdlUI/.
To use it with Visual Studio:

```
Go to project properies -> Debug page
Change Command Line Arguments

From: /client:"WcfTestClient.exe"
To: /client:"[PATH]WsdlUI.exe"
```